# How to use signal R in iOS?

Tags: swift, swift3, signalr

I am working with Signalr to push notifications and making real time chat. Does anyone have any tutorials to tell me how I can use signal r with Swift?

Comment: [try this lib](https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift)

Comment: You can use SwiftR, a simple swift client for SignalR. https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR

Comment: thank you very much